# Error while installing ops agent on Google VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm trying to install a Ops agent on a Google VM and some index files failed to download (error 404)

Command i used following documentation :

**curl -sSO https://dl.google.com/cloudagents/add-google-cloud-ops-agent-repo.sh**

**sudo bash add-google-cloud-ops-agent-repo.sh --also-install**

And i got error on those packages :

https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-ops-agent--all/main amd64 Packages
http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu impish/main amd64 Packages

Include in the error message i also got this :
https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-ops-agent--all Release' does not have a Release file

Does someone got the same issue recently ?

Here is the Log i got :

W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu impish Release' does not have a Release file.

N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

W: The repository 'https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-ops-agent--all Release' does not have a Release file.

N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu/dists/impish/main/binary-amd64/Packages 404 Not Found

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists/google-cloud-ops-agent--all/main/binary-amd64/Packages 404 Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

[.....]

add-google-cloud-ops-agent-repo.sh: line 202: lsb_release: command not found

[....]

W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu impish Release' does not have a Release file.

N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

W: The repository 'https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-ops-agent--all Release' does not have a Release file.

N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu/dists/impish/main/binary-amd64/Packages 404 Not Found

E: Failed to fetch https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists/google-cloud-ops-agent--all/main/binary-amd64/Packages 404 Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error likely indicates you're installing the agent on an unsupported OS.  Please check that your OS is in the list here:

https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/agents/ops-agent#supported_vms

Comment: Thanks for the idea, i checked but i'm using  a debian-9-stretch-v20181113 image, which is supposed to be supported

Comment: That's strange!  Can you please post the full error message?

Comment: I added the log at the bottom of the question

Comment: Well, I can confirm that those URLs return 404s.  I just created an Ubuntu Impish VM and was able to use the commands you provided to install the agent without any issues.

Comment: Thank you for your test, i have a question, why does it try to get elem in release for Ubuntu Impish if my distribution is Debian Stretch. I tried it on an Ubuntu Xenial and it worked fine. Maybe can you try on an Debian Distribution please ?

Comment: Right, sorry, I don't know why I tried Ubuntu.  I just tried with Debian 9 Stretch, and it again worked just fine.  Any chance you could try creating a new Debian 9 VM and testing there?

Comment: I just created a new empty Debian 9 VM, the image version differs from my existing VM (old one : v20181113, new one : debian-9-stretch-v20220118)
But indeed it works just fine for installation.
I will discuss to upgrade the version of the VM, thank you for your time and help (despite some huge delay in my response)

Comment: No problem at all - glad it worked out after all, and I'm sorry for all the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Try the commands from this link https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/1349.

Then run again the install of the agent.

It worked for me!